# Solution to differential equation $y'(x) = a * y(x)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recursive-algorithms

first of all: I am not a mathematician. I am struggling since a few hours with a simple differential equation which I would like to solve to approximate the expectation curve for computer simulations I am doing.

Recursive function:

$$y[x+1] = y[x] - c * y[x]^2$$

If c is small, this can be approximated by the following differential equation:

$$y'[x] = -c * y[x]^2$$

Which I do not manage to solve...

Sorry for such a low-level question here and thanks :)

EDIT: I know that $y$ at position $x$=0 equals 0.8.

Comment: solution for $y'[x] = -c  y[x]^2$ is $y=\frac{1}{cx+C}$ where $C$ is a constant defined by boundary condition(s)

Comment: How can I deduce $C$ from knowing what $y$ at position $x$ =0 is?

Comment: it's easy, $C=\frac{1}{y_0}=1.25$ ($cx=0$ when $x=0$). $y_0$ is the value of $y$ at $x=0$

Comment: Very nice, @Vasya !!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -cy^2$$
Rearranging:
$$\frac{dy}{y^2}=-cdx$$
Integrating both sides:
$$-\frac{1}{y}=-cx+d$$
for some constant of integration $d$. Rearranging:
$$y=\frac{1}{cx-d}$$

Comment: Really nice, thanks!
I forgot to mention: I know that at x=0, y=0.8.


Using your function for y, I can create almost the exact same expectation curve as with the recursive function, by using d=1.25.

Sorry, that I am such a noob. How can I deduce from knowing y[0] what my d should be?

Comment: Vasya solved this in his comment to my original question! Thanks a lot to all of you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You should solve the integral:

$$\int y^{-2}dy = -\int cdx$$

and you will get a solution to this aproximation.

Comment: Thank you, @greedoid!